# Getting error on uniswap "Unexpected error. Could not estimate gas for the swap." when trying to swap erc20

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, uniswap

I'm trying my hands on solidity and trying to make an erc20 token. Transfer function is working fine when I try to transfer it from one wallet to other. I'm also able to add liquidity to uniswapv2router with opentrading.
Transfer and TransferFrom is wokring fine for wallet to wallet transfer
If I try to swap tokens via uniswap (either direction) it gives me this error

[image: Unexpected error, Cloud not estimate gas for the swap]

```
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
    
    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= amount);
        uint256 tTeam = amount*10/100;    // tax amount
        uint256 remainingAmount = amount - tTeam; // to Send
        tokenBalance[from] = tokenBalance[from].sub(amount); // deduct from sender
        tokenBalance[to] = tokenBalance[to].add(remainingAmount); // add to recipient
        tokenBalance[address(this)] = tokenBalance[address(this)].add(tTeam); // add team Take to address
        emit Transfer(from, to, remainingAmount);
    }
   function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
```

I tried searching for the issue and found a couple of discussions where they are suggesting to add zeros in the end and increase slippage, thats not working either
[Cannot estimate gas error on Uniswap / Sushiswap](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/cannot-estimate-gas-error-on-uniswap-sushiswap)

Comment: Uniswap v2 requires calls to special function when tokens charge fee on transfer, for example w`swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` you should check if the frontend does support that call.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for reply, Strangely enough I deployed the contract to matic mainnet and it was working.